# OAuth Flow redirecting to "Unauthorized" page

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

In my web app, I use Spotify's OAuth flow to authenticate a user. I store the user's information in my database like this.

```
passport.use(
new SpotifyStrategy({
    clientID,
    clientSecret,
    callbackURL,
    proxy: true
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: profile.id });
    if (user) {
        user.accessToken = accessToken;
        user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        const replace = await user.save();
        return done(null, replace);
    }
    const newUser = await new User({spotifyId: profile.id, accessToken, refreshToken}).save();
    return done(null, user);    
})
```

In other words, if my user already exists in my database, then all I want to do is update the access/refresh token. If the user does not exist, then I want to create a new user document.

My problem occurs when a first-time user logs into my web app. I noticed that because this first-time user is not in my database, the redirect-url will go to a page that simply says unauthorized. However, this login-attempt will put the user's information into the database. So, even though the user initially went to the unauthorized page, if he or she tries to login again, it will work successfully. Likewise, any user that has already visited my website before will have no trouble logging in again.

So, if a user's information is not already in the database, they will be redirected to the unauthorized page when they go to the route '/auth/spotify/callback', and if they are already in, then the website will work as normal.

I can't figure out why this is happening. I initially thought that there might be a page that requires the authorization token, but because my user might not have one yet, it says unauthorized. But, I did some testing and found out that this is not the reason. I also tried redirecting to a page where the authorization token is not needed, and it still messes up. I also thought maybe I spelled the auth callback route incorrectly in the app, but I'm sure I spelled it correctly.

Here are my auth routes

```
app.get('/auth/spotify', 
    passport.authenticate('spotify', {
        scope: ['playlist-read-collaborative', 'playlist-read-private',
        'user-read-playback-state', 'user-modify-playback-state',
        'user-read-currently-playing', 'streaming']
    }),
    (req, res) => {
    }
)

app.get('/auth/spotify/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('spotify'),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/');
});
```

If anyone has an idea of how to fix this bug, I will greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. At the bottom, I should be returning newUser, not user.